# How to customize RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have created connected app in Salesforce and when user logins in for the first time, it gets redirected to RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage that ask permission from user to Allow\Deny. I would like to customize the page like changing button color, font style, size etc., I didn't find the page under Visualforce Pages. Where is RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage located in Salesforce and how to customize it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize this page - if you were able to do so, it would present a conflict of interest. The page presents a summary to the user of what your app might do on their behalf if the user authorizes access. Therefore allowing the app owner to change the page might lead to malicious behavior. It's a fair ask to be able to customize the visual elements of the page and leave the rest alone but Salesforce does not allow that.